SpringBoot Interceptor with AutoWired object Null
I am kind of new in SpringBoot. Can anyone help me here.
I am trying to intercept all incoming rest calls but in "RequestInterceptor" class a prehandle method I am getting NullPointer error. It seems like my CounterMetric class didn't AutoWired properly.
Class MonitoringConfig
package com.services.test.api;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeMeterRegistry;


@Configuration
public class MonitoringConfig {

@Bean    
public MeterRegistry getMeterRegistry() {        
    return new CompositeMeterRegistry();    
}
}


Class CounterMetric
package com.services.test.api;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeMeterRegistry;

@Component
public class CounterMetric{


private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

public CounterMetric(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;

}

public synchronized void logMetric(String serviceName, String method, String status, String caller){
     Counter.builder(serviceName)
            .description("Number of differnt API call processed through API")
            .tags("method", method)
            .tags("status", status)
            .tags("caller", caller)
            .register(meterRegistry).increment();
}
}


Class RequestInterceptor
package com.services.test.api.service;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jws;
import com.services.test.api.CounterMetric;

@Component
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class);

@Autowired
NuudayJWTParser tokenVerifier;

@Autowired
AuthFilter authFilter;

@Autowired
CounterMetric counterMetric;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) {

    
    
   
    logger.info("---------> "+counterMetric);
    String reqUri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (reqUri.contains("numberporting")) {
        counterMetric.logMetric("api_restcall_requests", "reqUri", "", "caller");
    }
    if (reqUri.contains("operatorcallback")) {
        counterMetric.logMetric("api_callback_requests", "reqUri", "", "caller");
        
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        @Nullable ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    // TODO 
   if (request.getHeader("Authorization") != null) {
    
 
    String tokenKey = authFilter.getTokenKey(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
    Jws<Claims> jws = tokenVerifier.getToken(tokenKey);
    String caller = jws.getBody().getAudience();
    ;
    String reqUri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (reqUri.contains("numberporting")) {
        counterMetric.logMetric("api_restcall_requests", reqUri, String.valueOf(response.getStatus()), caller);
    }
    if (reqUri.contains("operatorcallback")) {
        counterMetric.logMetric("api_callback_requests", reqUri, String.valueOf(response.getStatus()), caller);
        
    }
}
}
}

